# lwc : npx create-lwc-app not working

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am running the command and getting the following error :

```
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/create-lwc-app failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\itsme\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-07T05_41_06_502Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-lwc-app@latest' ] failed with code 1
```

Comment: Most likely you're not able to access internet or NPM registry is blocked etc.

Comment: i have set the proxy as well as used the registry command..still showing the error .. all other npm methods are working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting a proxy. In my case the first command helped.

```
$ npm config set proxy http://example:port
$ npm config set https-proxy http://example:port
```